# convert array object to single array

Tags: arrays, mongodb

here the following mongo schema

```
{ <br>
  "userID" : "id1", <br>
  "Languages" : { <br>
     "frontend" : [ { "fid":"ang1","fname":"AngularJS"},{"fid":"HT1","fname":"HTML" ], <br>
     "backend"  : [ {"bid":"mongo1","bname":"mongodb"},{"bid":"ora1","bname":"Oracle"}] <br>
  }
} <br> <br>
```

I need the following output

```
{ "languesNames" : ["AngularJS","HTML","mongodb","Oracle"]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the ***aggregation*** pipeline in mongodb. First use the `$addFields` option to create 2 arrays which contain the ***frontend*** and ***backend*** names. Then use the `$concatArrays` option to join these 2 arrays into one.

```js
db.collectionName.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "languesNamesFrontend": "$Languages.frontend.fname",
      "languesNamesBackend": "$Languages.backend.bname"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "languesNames": {
        "$concatArrays": [
          "$languesNamesFrontend",
          "$languesNamesBackend"
        ]
      },
      
    }
  }
])
```